# Add two webview in layout and get event click to webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to create an app with UI as follow..I have two webview add in screen..I want to when click to webview2,webview1 will hide and webview2 will fill fullscreen...If two webview load url is "http://www.google.com" ,it will display two webview separate but if I load an url different "http://www.google.com" as "http://www.youtube.com" it only display 1 webview youtube full screen..How I must do..Thank

Here is file XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >      
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout1" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview1"
    />
    </LinearLayout>     
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="4"                   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout2" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"           
    >
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview2"          
    />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and here is code in Activity:

```
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;        
    layout1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    layout2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);
    webview1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);        
    webview1.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    webview2=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview2);
    webview2.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    final LayoutParams lp=webview1.getLayoutParams();
    final LayoutParams lp1=webview2.getLayoutParams();                        
    lp.height=height;        
    lp1.height=height;

    webview1.setLayoutParams(lp);
    webview2.setLayoutParams(lp1);

    webview2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            webview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lp.height=height; 
            lp.width=width;
            webview2.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating 2 custom WebViews.

> WebView wv1 = findViewById(ID_WEBVIEW_1);
>
> WebView wv2 = findViewById(ID_WEBVIEW_2);
>
> if (wv1.getUrl() != "http://google.com" || wv2.getUrl() != "http://google.com")  {
>
> ```
>       ((ViewManager)entry.getParent()).removeView(entry);
> ```
>
> }

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewManager.html